# Let, flet, macrolet : is there a way to do a "class-let"?

Tags: common-lisp

I have a macro which defines a class under certain rules, pseudo-code :

```
(defvar *all-my-classes* nil)

(defmacro my-macro (param)
   `(if ,param
      (progn
         (defclass class-A () ...)
         (push class-A *all-my-classes*))
      (progn
         (defclass class-B () ...)
         (push class-B *all-my-classes*))))
```

I want to test the behaviour of the macro. Let is a convenient tool to mock variables. If I have an instance of `*all-my-classes*` running, I just have to do :

```
(let ((*all-my-classes* my-new-value)) ; generally `nil` for the test
   (my-macro false))
```

But I would like to conserve the correspondance between `*all-my-classes*` and the classes defined. Since I want to test all the cases, let us suppose `class-A` is defined in the current environment, and i want to test if running `(my-macro false)` correctly defines `class-B`.
Since it is just a test, I would like the test to assert that `class-B` is currently defined, and that `class-A` is undefined in the current local environment; then when the test is over, `class-B` is undefined in the global environment, and `class-A` is still defined (without any alteration).

This way would be the best for my use :

```
(let ((*all-my-classes* nil))
    (class-let ((class-A nil)   ; or a way to map to a pre-defined
                (class-B nil))  ; empty class temporarily.
       (my-macro false)
       (and
          ;; assert that the class is added to the list
          (eql (length *all-my-classes*) 1)
          ;; assert that class-A is not defined
          (null (find-class 'class-A))
          ;; assert that class-B is defined
          (find-class 'class-B))))
```

I've searched to see if I can undefine a class, but it seems to be complex and implementation-dependent. And I want to preserve the current environment.

Restarting LISP each time for each tests is too long, and I would prefer a solution without having to load-unload packages for each tests (I don't know if it could work and if the classes will be garbage-collected when unloading the package...).

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think so.

The mechanism of how classes are stored is completely implementation defined, they just need to conform to the MOP (at least as far as it is mandated by the standard).  However, the MOP does not prescribe anything that would make the classes registry dynamic.  In fact, types and class names are specified to be part of the global environment ([CLHS ch. 3.1.1.1](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_aaa.htm)), so it would be difficult for a conforming implementation to get dynamic here.

As you wrote, there is also no specified way to get rid of a class once defined.

As a rationale, I think that without this it would be very difficult to provide the kind of optimized runtime that the existing implementations have.  Class lookup needs to be fast.

Now, to get to the meta question: what are you trying to do?  Usually, while code is data, you should not confuse program logic with the programmed logic.  What you propose looks like it *might* be intended to have code represent data.  I'd advise to think about a clean separation and orthogonal representation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am new to common lisp, but i sure loved the meta concept. :)
The idea was to create "groups of classes" in one go. I have to do a macro because inheritance can vary for each class according to macro parametes.

The reason is : I have a lot of programming and meta-programming which repeat itself, so I wanted an automatic way to do that. Since I do BDD and TDD, I wanted a way to test the macros which specify the classes.

Comment: Yeah, well, I'd need to see an example.

Comment: How can I show an example ? Should I ask another question ? I don't think the comments are a good format...

Comment: Hmm.  I think that it is a different question, something like “here is a thing that I'm trying to model, this is how I am doing it now, is there a better way”.  This might be a question for a different Q&A site though, maybe Code Review.